# How to relate 2 tables to a third when the first 2 tables have a relationship?

Tags: normalization, database-design

For once, I find myself at an utter loss in terms of coming up with a good question title.

Consider the three following tables. Each has additional columns, but only the columns relevant to the relationships between the tables are mentioned:

- Table `a` has a primary key `a_id`
- Table `b` has a primary key `b_id` and a column `a_id` which is a foreign key to `a` (one-to-many relationship)
- Table `reference` has a primary key `ref_id`

`reference` is a list of sources that are cited to substantiate information contained in the other 2 tables. As such, I need tables to relate them together. Both `a` and `b` have many-to-many relationships with `reference`, but there is an additional complication: a footnote number. This footnote number must be unique for each `a` and `reference` pair, but it is only required when a relationship between a `b` and the same `reference` exists. (Of course, that `b` must be related to the same `a`.) The best way I have come up with to represent this relationship so far is a pair of tables:

`bridge_a_reference`:

- Columns: `a_id`, `ref_id`, `footnote_num` (nullable)
- Primary key: `a_id`, `ref_id`
- Foreign keys: `a_id` to table `a`; `ref_id` to table `reference`

`bridge_b_reference`:

- Columns: `b_id`, `a_id`, `ref_id`
- Primary key: `b_id`, `ref_id`
- Foreign keys: `b_id`, `a_id` to table `b`; `a_id`, `ref_id` to table `bridge_a_reference`

This ensures data consistency. There can only be a relationship between `b` and `reference` if a corresponding relationship between `a` and `reference` exists and `b` is related to the correct `a`. It also ensures that the footnote number will be consistent for all `a`/`reference` pairs. However, it's redundant, storing the relationship between `a` and `b` a second time (though enforced to be consistent, at least), and it doesn't ensure the footnote number is required for the `b`/`reference` relationships.

I've tried rearranging the tables in my head a few times, but everything else I can come up allows some kind of inconsistency (`b` to `reference` relationships without the corresponding `a` to `reference` or `b` to `a` relationship or inconsistent footnote numbers for the `a`/`reference` pairs.) How can I better structure my bridge tables to eliminate redundancy and ensure the footnote requirements? Is it even possible?

Comment: How about adding the `footnote_sum` (as `NOT NULL`) to table `bridge_b_reference` and then modify the FK to `(a_id, ref_id, footnote_sum)` to table `bridge_a_reference` ?

Comment: @ypercube There are `a`/`reference` pairs that do not have a corresponding `b`/`reference` pair, and those entries should not have a footnote number.

Comment: Those would still have `NULL` in that table (`bridge_a_reference`). but when you want to add a related row in the `bridge_b_reference` table, you'd have (because of the FK) to modify first the row in the `bridge_a_reference` and assign a value to that null.

Comment: @ypercube Oh, I misunderstood. I see. That would ensure that the footnote number is required for the `b`/`reference` table, but at the cost of more redundancy.

Comment: I think it can be improved a bit. Let me form an answer. Can you clarify what you mean with "unique" in the sentence: *"This footnote number must be unique for each a and reference pair,"*

Comment: Can there be 2 rows with same `a_id` and same `footnote_num` in the `bridge_a_ref` table?

Comment: @ypercube No, the footnote numbers should be unique across a single `a_id`. In the sentence you outlined, what I meant was that there can only be a single footnote number associated with an `a`/`reference` pair. This makes it unsuitable as a column on `bridge_b_reference` since that would allow for multiple footnote numbers to be associated with a single `a`/`reference` pair. It boils down to the footnote number must be consistent when multiple `b`s are associated with the same `reference` and same `a`.

Comment: @ypercube If I were to apply a `UNIQUE` constraint, it would be on `(a_id, footnote_num)`. I will edit the question shortly. My apologies for the poor wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion so you can enforce the constraints you want declaratively. (I've simplified the table names a bit, removed the `bridge_` prefix.)

We remove `footnote_num` from:

```
Table:      a_ref         -- was named:  bridge_a_reference
     a_id, 
     ref_id
Primary key: 
     (a_id, ref_id)
Foreign keys:
     a_id  -> a
     ref_id -> reference
```

We add this table - which will basically store only those rows from `a_ref` with footnote, those you want to add children into the `b_ref`:

```
Table:      a_ref_with_footnote 
    a_id, 
    ref_id,
    footnote_num
Primary key: 
    (a_id, ref_id)
Unique key:
    (a_id, footnote_num)
Foreign keys: 
    (a_id, ref_id)  -> a_ref
```

And finally the 3rd table stays as in your design except the foreign keys which now reference the intermediate table (`a_ref_with_footnote`):

```
 Table:     b_ref         -- was named: bridge_b_reference:
     a_id, 
     b_id, 
     ref_id,
 Primary key: 
     (b_id, ref_id)
 Foreign keys: 
     (a_id, b_id) -> b
     (a_id, ref_id) -> a_ref_with_footnote
```

Comment: I decided to go with a small variation of this. I eliminated the foreign key from `a_ref_with_footnote` to `a_ref`, and I created a view that combines it with the `a_ref` table to get a complete list of all the references associated with a row in `a` directly or indirectly. This way, entries in `a_ref` are not required for entries in `b_ref`, which makes things a little looser.